# Accessing UI thread collection from worker thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I am writing an application in c# wpf in Visual studio 2012. I am using mvvm.
I have an ObservableCollectionCriteriaCollection which belongs to UI thread ,for fetching data from database i am using Task.Factory because data is huge and kept on remote server.
when i click on GetData Button following code is executed.
my code is like this:

```
void GetData(object obj)
{
        if (CriteriaCollection == null)         
        CriteriaCollection = new ObservableCollection<Criteria>();

        if (SelectedIndex != null && SelectedCriteria != null)
        { 
                bool results = this.CriteriaCollection.Any(report => 
                     report.CriteriaName.Equals(
                                 this.SelectedCriteria.CriteriaName.ToString()));
                if (!results)
                {
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        IsBusy = true;
                        Criteria newCriteria = new Criteria();

                        ExecuteGetDataFromDB(null);

                      ///some code which populates values and fills newCriteria

                        CriteriaCollection.Add(newCriteria);
                        }).ContinueWith(result =>
                        {
                            IsBusy = false;
                        });
                }
        }    
}
```

I get an exception at line   CriteriaCollection.Add(newCriteria); saying `This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.`
Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUI related code can only be executed from the GUI thread or with a dispatcher from another thread:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
{
    // your GUI related code here
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have for creating the Task to do the background work is not quite correct, I believe you want something more like this:

```
        IsBusy = true;

        Task<SomeResult>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Criteria newCriteria = new Criteria();
            return ExecuteGetDataFromDB(newCriteria);

        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default)
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            CriteriaCollection.Add(t.Result);

            IsBusy = false;
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

What this does is create the Task on a background thread and when it completes 'continues with' on the UI thread and hopefully you won't get the exception any more.

Note you'll have to define the class `SomeResult` as the return type from `ExecuteGetDataFromDB` method.